# GATK 4.1.4.0 Mutect stats output

Tags: wgs, gatk

I have adapted my pipeline to the new filtering strategies implemented in gatk 4.1.4.0 and while looking at its output I noticed that the stat file generated by mutect2 has a negative number:

```
callable -1.538687311E9
```

I did not find the documentation about this file content but in the gatk forum it is mentioned that is should represent the number of bases above a certain coverage (10 by default). 
This happened for a WGS sample, while for WES I obtain a more sensible value (well, at least positive and integer, even if maybe a tad high):

```
callable        8.6884303E7
```

Has this happened to anyone else?
I compared the resulting calls obtained for the WGS with a previous version of mutect2 and they are comparable-ish (98% of the new "ones" are in common with the "old" ones), but I am still worried that something fishy is happening, expecially considering that the filtering step of the pipeline uses this stats file.

Comment: quick followup: seems to be a bug due to an integer overflow (yay Java!), GATK developers have fixed it and I'm trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by the OP -- it was a bug that has been fixed in a subsequent release, 4.1.5.0. See the release notes here: https://github.com/broadinstitute/gatk/releases/tag/4.1.5.0

> Made callable sites a Long to avoid integer overflow (#6303)

Issue ticket: https://github.com/broadinstitute/gatk/issues/6302

Comment: Hey ya, this could be a useful answer if you would provide some details, like the version where the bug is fixed and a link to the changelog. Right now it provides nothing than what OP wrote.

Comment: Sure; done. I was just looking to not have it show up as unanswered anymore since the problem was effectively solved. But I get your point.